# Open When Minimized On Key Down

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something like what Steam has; when in the game and you click shift+tab it opens overlay with data relative to Steam. As I understand, this can be done since Steam is ON when game is played through steam. It can also be done by assigning a key to open program through Windows settings, but my question is whether or not program can listen to the KeyPressEvent event even if it's minimized? In other wards, can I open the program even if it's minimized by just pressing the assigned key?

Comment: I think a low level keyboard hook is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to write a keylogger.
See [the MSDN Forum question for "keylogger code in C# .NET"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed63b033-663a-4a20-80a5-a732d31e9486/keylogger-code-in-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral) for an example.

Comment: Please do not provide link-only answers. Include at least the relevant parts of the linked content so that the answer is useful although the link is broken. Try to make the link specific, not just "here", because that does not help avoiding dangerous sites.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes you can,  it's called a hook.  Here are some basic resources -  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_keyboardhook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_keyboardhook)

What it does is basically add your own event handler to the systems handling chain.

There are numerous  examples in c++ and C# / vb for this and to not too complicated.

But: if you want to "overlay an app with another"  you might come across a problem  with focus switching.  If your program will run in fullscreen  mode then bringing your other app to focus will 'blurr'  the game application  which is equal to minimizing the game.  The way steam probably does it is that it's actually  the game that listens for shift+tab Keys and reacts within its own display context.